# Is there an equivalent of MATLAB's edge(I, method, threshold) in opencv where method = 'zerocross'?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I need to translate the following line from matlab to cpp and get the exact same result:

```
im_zerocross = 
double(edge(im,'zerocross',0));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add a sample image, the expected calculation result and what you have tried so far! [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Zero crossing edge detector in MATLAB is synonymous to Laplacian operator in OpenCV.

It finds the second order derivatives along X and Y directions in the image. Every zero crossing in this result corresponds to an edge in the image.

**Usage:**

```
import cv2

# read image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('apple.jpg',0)

# apply Laplacian operator
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
```

The last parameter `cv2.CV_64F` is to give the result in `float` data type similar to `double` in MATLAB.

Go through [this post for details and relevant code](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/db5/tutorial_laplace_operator.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I tried it and also read the post you mentioned, and i'm still unable to get the same result as i have with this matlab line:

im_zerocross = 
double(edge(im,'zerocross',0));

how does the third parameter used in the opencv's version? also, should there be another change due to the casting to double?

Comment: Also, in the matlab's version the output of edge is a binary image:

"BW = edge(I) returns a binary image BW containing 1s where the function finds edges in the grayscale or binary image I and 0s elsewhere."

Comment: @OriHirshfeld Did you try using `convertScaleAbs` as mentioned in the link?

Comment: note: `CV_64F` is always fp64. python's built-in `float` is fp64 (differs from what a "float" is in C-like languages). the result is a numpy array of `np.float64`.